# Date range for CodePlex projects not working

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

Seems the date range import for CodePlex projects on Careers isn't working correct.

After updating the project it shows:

> CodePlex, ; followed by 15 people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Martin, thanks for reporting this issue. The problem is that your commits from Mercurial aren't correctly mapped to your user profile in CodePlex. For the date range displayed on your careers profile, the dates of *your* first and last commit are relevant.

In other words: CodePlex is aware that the project is owned by your CodePlex user, "MartinBuberl", but unfairly considers all your commits to be made by a different user named "Martin Buberl".

This can also be verified by diving into the codeplex API:
https://www.codeplex.com/api/users/MartinBuberl/repos?expanded=true

Note that for the Buildscreen project, CodePlex reports: "Commits":103, "UserCommits":0

Try committing to the project with your exact CodePlex username, that should hopefully fix the problem.

Comment: You're right. Seems that my accounts got mixed merging CodePlex w/ Microsoft. Thanks for your help.